# Is this example in Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual correct?

Tags: hash

[image: skiena, hashing and strings]

i think the above is incorrect; specifically, i think `H` isn't bijective. say our alphabet is the lowercase letters `[a-z]` and that `char(a) = 0`. then, e.g., `H("abc") = H("bc")`.

am i missing something?

Comment: $H(\text{"abc"}) = 26^{2}*0 + 26*char(\text{'b'}) + char(\text{'c'}) = H(\text{"bc"})$ though, right?

Comment: Yeah you are right, I was mistaken. The function seems to be bijective if you restrict yourself to strings of a fixed length. What is the context? Is it the Rabin-Karp algorithm?

Comment: the above is from the introductory paragraph in a section on Hashing and Strings. your guess is p much correct; skiena (the author) introduces rabin-karp later in on that section. and i think you're also correct in saying that $H$ would be bijective if its domain was restricted to strings of a given length (fixed-length bitstrings come to mind as a "real-world" example).

Comment: In Rabin-Karp you'll be using $H$ as a "rolling hash" function over a window of fixed length, so $H$ is bijective for this purpose. Of course, you're then going to consider $H \bmod p$, for some (prime) integer $p$, which makes it non-bijective anyway.